# Understanding how multiple local TeamCity build agents work together

Tags: teamcity

So far I have been using Travis and was quite happy about it (although it only provides Linux environments) however I am considering to give TeamCity a try and work with YouTrack as well. My current scenario is the following:

I have a project that consists of multiple applications and libraries that should are platform independant targeting Windows, macOS and Linux and bundled together for each of those platforms. Everytime I finish a feature branch and merge it to the development branch I need to manually pull the new changes, compile and run test suites on Windows and macOS separately.

I'd like to be able to push changes to the development branch and have the CI tool handle all platforms simultaneously. Therefore I noticed that I can setup an online TeamCity server (for example on DigitalOcean) and have a Linux build agent running besides it while having a Windows build agent on my local desktop computer and a macOS build agent on my (local) Macbook in order to let those machines use the local toolchains native to their systems.

**First of all I'd like to know whether this is a feasible setup in general.** I considered using Docker images of build agents until I noticed that a Windows build agent only runs on Windows servers and I'd have to configure the container myself with installing msbuild and such. Therefore I considered just using my local machines with their already setup toolchains as build slaves in this case.

**Finally, I'd like to know whether TeamCity provides build queues or something similiar.** What I am referring to is the following situation: I am on the train and finishing something on my Macbook and merge it into the branch. However my desktop with the Windows build agent is offline at the moment. Does it work through the queued commits/builds once I boot it up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your scenario seems feasible to accomplish with teamcity. You could have a set up with 3 builds all with the same trigger. Each build would have the build steps for a specific operating system. If you had all machines and agents running they would likely all be triggered at the same time and perform their builds in parallel.

I"m not sure what you are trying to say in paragraph 4 about the "windows build agents only runs on windows servers". Windows build agents can run on desktop versions on windows such as windows 7 or windows 10.

Yes, teamcity has a queue. If an agent is offline the build will be held in the queue until the agent is back online or the build is cancelled.